# Is it possible to use parameterize imports with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, virtualenv, python-module

I am using pytest to test a project I am working on. I have a project structure like

```
|my_project
||__init__.py
||my_code.py
||test.py
```

and `test.py` looks like

```
# contents of test.py
import .my_code

def test_function():
  ...
...
```

To run the tests, I can just run `python -m pytest` from this directory. So far so good.

But for the code to run remotely, I have to use Pants to build a virtual environment so that the import statement will actually look like:

```
import long.path.to.my_project.my_code as my_code
```

I want to make sure that the code still works in this virtual environment as well, so right now I have a different file called `test_venv.py` with identical tests, where the only difference is the import.

```
# contents of test_venv.py
import long.path.to.my_project.my_code as my_code

def test_function():
   ...
...
```

This does work, but it's very annoying to have two almost identical test files. Is there a way to make the import statement parameterized, so that I can tell pytest where I want to import from when I run the test?

Comment: Try this out: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with @morhc's suggestion to use [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html), I figured out a way. It involves using parameterized fixtures and `importlib`. I set up the fixture as follows.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=['local', 'installed'])
def my_code_module(request):
    if request.param == 'local':
        return importlib.import_module("my_code")
    if request.param == 'installed':
        return importlib.import_module("long.path.to.my_project.my_code")
```

Then write the tests to request the fixture as follows.

```
def test_code(my_code_module):
    assert my_code_module.whatever() == ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine imports. Do one way, catch exception, do the other way.

```
try:
    import .my_code
except ImportError:
    import long.path.to.my_project.my_code as my_code

def test_function():
   ...
...
```

I'm not sure, may be it's should be

```
try:
    import long.path.to.my_project.my_code as my_code
except ImportError:
    import .my_code
```

Comment: yeah I was doing this! But really I want to test it under both sets of imports. So what I'd like is for pytest to do 

import .my_code

and then restart, and then run

import long.path.to.my_project.mycode as my_code

and run the identical set of tests